# What can we do so that users of our custom UIView can customize that UIView in XIB?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, custom-controls, xib

The biggest problem of custom UIView is that all we see is a white rectangle in XIB.

We can't customize some properties at all. For example, if our custom subView has a label, it's kind of nice to be able to set texts for that label straight in XIB.

[image]

Something like UIButton does.

Is this even doable?

Is XIB design merely as short cuts and that the real codes are in codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no real way to add entries in the Interface Builder "Attributes Inspector" panel (the one on your capture) to allow your to customize values like you do for built-in Cocoa classes.

---

*(well to be exact, some blogs explain some ways to convert old Xcode3 plugins — that were able to do that back in Xcode3 — to Xcode4 plugins, but this is not officially documented and quite complex to setup an needs a dedicated Xcode project just to create your custom view, declare its IB palette, write some associates code and embbed it in a xcode plugin…)*

---

However, **you still have one possibility**, even if it is not very handy, to customize any property of any object in your XIB right in Interface Builder instead of doing it by code.

Simply go in the "Identity Inspector" (the tab before the Attributes Inspector, <kbd>Cmd-Alt-3</kbd>) and use the "User Defined Runtime Attributes" table to fill the name/keypath of the properties you want to change and indicate their value.

[image: Customize value in IB from keyPath]

In practice however, I have rarely seen it used in XIB files I work with, because it is not as nice as a dedicated "Attributes Inspector" palette, and you have to type the *exact* name of the property in the table so you can affect a value to it: there is no list of modifiable properties build for you with nice text fields and checkboxes in the panel to help you… but it still works like a charm!

---

Please feel free to send a request to Apple (using their feedback tools) to ask for this feature, as you are not the first one to hope this could be possible, and will not be the last to request it, so maybe hopefully Apple will receive enough requests and they will implement it…

Comment: thanks. So I defined linkColor as user defined runtime attributes. Then when can I access this so called linkColor? So linkColor need to be a property of UIView and that's available after [super initWithDecoder:]?

Comment: Yes that's exactly that. In my capture you can see the object that was selected in my XIB was of class `OHAttributedLabel` (a [custom class of mine](http://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)) which is a subclass of `UILabel` to which I added some properties, including a `@property(retain) UIColor* linkColor`. Configuring the value of the `linkColor` property value in the "User Defined Runtime Attributes" — as in the capture — makes this value be set when the object is instanciated by the XIB, and so te value is set by the time it's `initWithCoder:` method is called.

Comment: Yep this solution is good, the only drawback is that you need to enter the property's exact name and type yourself in IB in that table and make sure it matches the ones in your code, but apart from that it's pretty useful. Note that you can also use a keyPath instead of just a property name in there (If you don't know what keyPaths are, search "KVC" in Apple documentation and read the "Key-Value-Coding Programming Guide" that's quite powerful too)

Comment: Simple example for using keyPath here: if your custom view contains e.g. a `@property UILabel* titleLabel`, you can enter `titleLabel.textColor` or `titleLabel.numberOfLines` and even `titleLabel.layer.borderWidth` and `titleLabel.layer.borderColor`… in the "keyPath" column of the "User Defined Runtime Attributes" table and indicate a corresponding value for each of these!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

First, in your custom view add the following property (guessing you work with ARC feature) :

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel myLabel;
```

Now, in your xib, be sure the main view is the kind of your custom view.
Add a label where you want in the view.
Click on the custom view, and link the label to myLabel using the connection inspector.

Comment: That's one way to do it. But I want' the label to be the original label.

Answer (score 0):

The storyboard/nib shows what the interface looks like before your code runs. If you want to see it in storyboard you have to build it in storyboard. If you have custom objects there is a basic object in storyboard to use as a placeholder, but it won't show content loaded in code.